# How to know if your site was properly redirected

Tags: google-search-console, redirects, 301-redirect

How do you know that your site is properly redirected?

I have migrated my site from Joomla to WordPress and I gave all the list of webpages to my developer

Old website URLs:

1. www.example.com
2. www.example.com/about
3. www.example.com/services-skills.html
4. www.example.com/services-skills2.html

New website URLs:

1. www.example.com
2. www.example.com/about
3. www.example.com/services-skills
4. www.example.com/services-skills2

I retained the URL structure because I want the transition everything seemingly.

It has been 2 weeks after the site went live and now I checked Google webmaster/console and it gave me a list of 404 pages error when I visited the old URL it shows 404 but it displayed the new website design.

I also did a query of Google and after clicking it redirects me the result it shows page not found error displaying the new redesigned website.

But when I try to search for my homepage it displays correctly.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. It is almost backwards.It may be best for you to post information on how you redirected your site so that we can see if there are any errors. It sounds like there is a problem.

Comment: you have a point but I think that's another question how the site was directed. Based on my examples I found out that the home page was the the page that was properly redirected. Because when I did a query on google showing my the result of my homepage I redirects me to the new site that was redesigned. Now when I did a query for my specific skills/services the result still shows but when I clicked it, it displays Page not found. Now I want to know if all the pages were properly redirected correctly even if what method was used(plugin, htaccess, hosting)

Comment: Without code, I am not sure I can help you to know for sure. The only thing I can say is wait until all/enough of the pages have been fetched by Google, wait a day or two and test again. You scenario sounds strange enough that I am not sure I can even guess at this point. Not trying to be snotty. Honest! I just have no idea. I will have to think on this for a while.

Comment: it's ok i understand here's another scenario so that we can be on both same page:. domain.com/about-us.html and I want to redirect it to domain.com/about......if I type domain.com/about-us.html it will automatically redirect me to domain.com/about without displaying PAGE NOT FOUND

Comment: Oh! Redirects do not show Page Not Found. This is presumably because the page can be found elsewhere using the redirect. Page Not Found are a result of a 404 error where a requested page does not exist. In the case of a redirect, it the redirect works correctly, you will ultimately see a 202 Ok after the redirect. Am I in the ball park??

Comment: exactly if the redirect is correct then no need to display PAGE NOT FOUND instead it will immediately redirect to the new desired page. So with regards to my main question if the redirection was done right i assume it was only the home page that was properly redirected since when I typed the old permalink it automatically redirects me to the new redesigned website. but for other pages were not

Comment: Yes. It sounds like you are understanding things well. What CMS are you using? That may help you get an answer. I do not use a CMS except for the one I wrote so I am not familiar with them.

Comment: the old site was joomla and migrated to wordpress i listed all my sites including the URL structure so that my developer would refer to it and wont randomly generate URL pages